# parser generator that generates stand-alone C++ code

Tags: c++, parsing, parser-generator

Is there a LALR parser generator that produces stand-alone C++ code? I am hoping that it would generate two files named something like "Parser.cpp" and "Parser.hpp," and the generated parser is implemented in a single class (that I can wrap in whatever namespace) that I can use for my parsing needs.

I want to use it for fun (i.e. small personal projects), and I'd like the output to be stand-alone (without any headers) so that I know I can compile it wherever I have a C++ compiler.

**The search so far:**

I've looked at flex/bison, but AFAIK they both require special headers and libraries. I've also looked at ANTLR a little bit, but it is not obvious to me that it can generate stand-alone C++ code. If someone can confirm that it can, then I might look more into it.

Comment: ANTLR 3.x can generate C code, which can be used in C++, but it does not generate C++ code. There's work being done on a C++ target, but that's still in the early stages, AFAIK.

Comment: For a list of parser generators, including the class of parsers they generate (LALR, LL, GLR, etc.) and target languages, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators

Comment: If you write your grammar in C++ to begin with then you wouldn't need to generate C++ code. Both AXE and Spirit allow you to do exactly that, unless you have problems with recursive descent. You can also check wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GOLD Parser](http://goldparser.org/) (Bart Kiers mentioned the list on Wikipedia) has support for C and C++ languages. It does not generate a completely self-contained C/C++ source code file. All it does is the generation of Lexer/Parser tables which can be consumed by the "parsing engine".

To accomplish your task (or something similar) I did the following:

1. Prepare your LALR grammar in Gold's format
2. Generate parsing tables (one binary file)
3. Use an old trick to convert the binary file into a header file like

   unsigned char ParseTable[] = { ... };
4. Modify the loader from the "parsing engine" sources (or use the C version which supports in-memory loading, as I remember)
5. Combine the sources for the GPEngine (if it is a C++ version) into the .h/.cpp pair.
6. Append the ParseTable to .cpp

Sure, it's not that straightforward, but all the steps can in principle be done within a single "combine" script which can be used with a number of grammars.

I guess the major drawback is the fact that GOLD is closed-source and windows-only (it means that to produce the parsing tables you have to use Windows machine).

Answer (score 1):

ANTLR [can generate C++](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=29130834) code although IMHO I find the support for C++ is a bit weak, it is more like C code. Still it is a good environment to work with ANTLRWorks giving you a graphical representation of your syntax tree.

Comment: The cool thing about *ANTLR* is its integration with *stringtemplates* and that excludes C++. It is very unlikely that *stringtemplates* will be ported to C++ because it's features are deeply integrated with Java like languages (like C# for example). The other cool thing is the impressive graphical grammar debugger - but personally I find that more distracting than helpful.

Comment: @PatrickFromberg yes ANTRL definitely shines in Java, been a while since I used it so probably it has gotten better with C++ since I used it (2011)

Answer (score 1):

The output from flex+bison consists of two .c files and one .h file. These are completely stand-alone, in that they are all you need to compile into your application to make use of the parser. There are no additional libraries or headers needed (beside the standard C ones).

Unless I've misunderstood your requirements, you definitely can do what you want with flex+bison.

Comment: Really? When I used it, I think I needed to link (-lfl) when I compiled.

Comment: Actually, after a little more research, I think you are [right](http://www.thebinaryidiot.com/archives/2010/03/06/flex-bison-cpp-example/)...

Comment: Or actually maybe not: http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Cxx.html. I've just tried to compile the sources from a linux box without flex/bison installed and it complained it couldn't find FlexLexer.h. Srry.. I probably should have been more thorough before accepting...

Comment: I wonder if this might be a consequence of specifying a C++ parser rather than a C parser. In pure C there are no additional dependencies. -- Just read your link and yes, that is the case. I suppose you could always take a copy of FlexLexer.h and add it to your project. Or you could create your own C++ wrapper for a pure C parser.

Comment: Both flex and bison are able to create C++ classes. Just take a look at one of my defunct projects: https://github.com/rioki/libConfig/tree/master/Source The only downside is that bison uses a union and thus you need to use pointers everywhere. May work better with C++11, but I did not try.